# Query that returns data in tabular format (multiple columns)

Tags: sql, formatting

I'm wondering if tSQL can return my data in a tabular format. I've never seen SQL do this, and maybe it's the wrong tool for this job, but it would save me some steps if it were possible. Right now I'm exporting data to Excel and using VBA to create the tables.

Say I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table
(SomeDate nvarchar(20), SomeEvent nvarchar(10)) 

INSERT INTO temp_table
VALUES 
,(convert(nvarchar(20), '1/1/2016', 23), 'foo') 
,(convert(nvarchar(20), '1/1/2016', 23), 'bar') 
,(convert(nvarchar(20), '1/1/2016', 23), 'left') 
,(convert(nvarchar(20), '1/1/2016', 23), 'right') 
,(convert(nvarchar(20), '1/1/2016', 23), 'in' )
,(convert(nvarchar(20), '1/1/2016', 23), 'out') 
,(convert(nvarchar(20), '1/2/2016', 23), 'foo') 
,(convert(nvarchar(20), '1/2/2016', 23), 'in') 
,(convert(nvarchar(20), '1/2/2016', 23), 'right' )
,(convert(nvarchar(20), '1/2/2016', 23), 'out' )
,(convert(nvarchar(20), '1/3/2016', 23), 'foo' )
,(convert(nvarchar(20), '1/3/2016', 23), 'right' )
,(convert(nvarchar(20), '1/3/2016', 23), 'left' )
,(convert(nvarchar(20), '1/3/2016', 23), 'bar' )
,(convert(nvarchar(20), '1/3/2016', 23), 'in' )
,(convert(nvarchar(20), '1/3/2016', 23), 'something')
```

Can SQL build me an output that looks like this?

```
1/1/2016    1/2/2016    1/3/2016
  foo         foo         foo
  bar                     bar
  left                    left
  right       right       right
  in          in          in
  out         out    
                        something
```

I've been fiddling with UNION joins and aggregate functions, but I can't put the pieces together to make it work. I need the data sorted, and blank fields where there isn't any data, as shown. My data can vary quite a bit - different numbers of SomeDates, to use this simple example, and varying values for SomeEvent.

Possible? Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: You can, but you ought not, most would say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a ranking function and `PIVOT`:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT SomeEvent, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SomeEvent) AS RN
              FROM temp_table
              )
    ,cte2 AS (SELECT a.*, b.RN
              FROM temp_table a
              JOIN cte b
                ON a.SomeEvent = b.SomeEvent
              )
SELECT [2016-01-01],[2016-01-02],[2016-01-03]
FROM cte2
PIVOT (MAX (SomeEvent) FOR SomeDate IN ([2016-01-01],[2016-01-02],[2016-01-03]))pvt
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ebf36/8/0)

To make it dynamic you'll query all the dates and store them in a list, and use dynamic sql like this:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) 
       ,@cols VARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' +   QUOTENAME(SomeDate)                     
                                    FROM temp_table                         
                                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
                                    ,1,1,'')

SET @sql = ';with cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT SomeEvent, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SomeEvent) AS RN
              FROM temp_table
              )
    ,cte2 AS (SELECT a.*, b.RN
              FROM temp_table a
              JOIN cte b
                ON a.SomeEvent = b.SomeEvent
              )
SELECT '+@cols+'
FROM cte2
PIVOT (MAX (SomeEvent) FOR SomeDate IN ('+@cols+'))pvt'
EXEC (@sql)
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ebf36/12/0)

Comment: Hey Hart, thanks so much for this. It's a bit above my skill level, I'm afraid, so I'll need to take this one home with me and fool around with it - never worked with PIVOT before. But let me play with this. Also, re: your earlier comment, do you think it would be unwise for me to pursue this idea? Just asking.

Comment: SQL is my favorite hammer, so I use it for lots of things. In this case, I think you'll find that performance is good and it doesn't need to be done elsewhere.

Comment: Excellent, this will be a learning experience for me. Thanks again!